# recognize website based off of list by user

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a long list of domains that the user makes by himself.  The chrome extension has content scripts to get the url.

sorry if this is a duplicate, researched the web but couldnt find anything to my specific needs

So basically, how can i recognize the website.  The user could input `www.google.com, or google.com or http://google.com or https://www.google.co`

using regex, how can my extension be absolutely sure that they are currently on that url.  (i wouldnt want for `https://www.codeup.net/google` to be recognized as being `google.com`)

lets say the list is inside the variable 'listUrl' and i get the url of the current page using `document.URL`, then what would the function `isUrlInList()` be like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use location.hostname as that will give you the current domain name. When users add a new domain I would strip everything except the hostname and then I would use `indexOf` to determine if that domain was in my array of domains.

```
var domains = ['stackoverflow.com', 'google.com', 'yahoo.com'];
var current = location.hostname;

if(domains.indexOf(current) !== -1){
   // domain is in list
} else {
   // domain is not in list
}
```

This would work even if you didn't strip out everything but the hostname, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

What you need to do is iterate over all the URLs in the list you have and check each one of them against the current URL, using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

The only reason to use regular expressions is if you would like to allow the users to add regular expression patterns to the URL list.

And, you will probably want to to a case insensitive comparison so then you would normalize the case for all URLs in the list, and also the current URL when checking.

Comment: yes, but my problem was if the page is "www.net.com/google.com", then indexof would find google.com and my extension would believe the page is google.com